# SonicWALL Global VPN Client fails to connect when using a UMTS internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, internet, umts

I know there are some questions here about problems with connecting via SonicWALL on xbox, mac, ... my problem seems to me a bit weirder and I can't figure where to look for a solution.

The situation: SonicWALL client is configured and works when I use a normal internet connection (in Germany DSL), so the configuration of the client itself should be fine.

My problem: sometimes I'm at places where I don't have a DSL connection, so I would have to share my built-in UMTS connection of my Lenovo Edge laptop (Windows 7, connected to the internet by the preinstalled Access Connections program) via virtual WiFi. My business laptop (Windows 7) can use this virtual WiFi for all internet stuff, I can use the Barracuda website (SSL-VPN) from my company and get access to almost all what I want, but it's not very comfortable and some database connections I can't use via Barracuda, so I must use the SonicWALL client in some cases (and want to use it for all others cases) - but when I try to connect from my business laptop using the SonicWALL client, it won't connect. The log doesn't give that much information:

```
Starting ISAKMP phase 1 negotiation.
An error occurred.
The peer is not responding to phase 1 ISAKMP requests.
```

And it's starting again - takes about 18 seconds until the line with `An error occured` comes.

I have no idea if I have to change the configuration on the SonicWALL client (despite it's working when used with a different internet connection) or if there's some way to configure the virtual WiFi settings or even something in the UMTS settings.

What I tried so far: switching off Windows firewall on the Lenovo laptop which provides the UMTS connection, also tried to deactive anti virus software there, so those shouldn't block anything. But it doesn't have any effect on the above scenario.

Trying to set the MTU on a lower (1200) or higher (2000) value on my Lenovo laptop with `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "xxx" mtu=1200 store=persistent` with xxx being my virtual wifi and/or my umts connection. Also without any effect.

Settings in the SonicWALL client: tried to disable NAT traversal (cause I read somewhere that this might help) with no effect, tried to higher timeout from 3 to 5 seconds with the only effect that it takes longer until the error message comes.

When I `netsh interface ip show config` on my Lenovo laptop I see that the gateway metric of the UMTS connection has a quite high (?) value of 256, but it's the only connection on that laptop, so I can't believe that this may be a problem (and I don't see how to easily change that value).

Any idea where to look further? Many thanks in advance.